# Java Объекты. Производительность. Различия

Tags: java, объекты, производительность

**Дано:** Класс у которого прописаны множество функций(без создания дополнительных объектов). Один из других классов каждую секунду вызывает его некоторые функции.

**Вопрос**: Что лучше, каждый раз создавать новый анонимный объект который возвращает уже готовые данные(но при своей работе создает множество переменных и делает мат.расчеты), или же статистический объект который хранит все переменные и обновляет их по мере вызывания?

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос. Приложите какой-то минимальный пример. Или хотяб на словах опишите,  что за объект с готовыми данными и статический, который что-то там обновляет. И да, я думаю (да и, скорее всего, не один я), что на ваш вопрос нет и не будет объективного ответа, ибо решение зависит как от конкретной задачи, так и от ваших личных предпочтений. Ибо сколько программистов, столько и стилей писать код)

Comment: Предположим этот класс, обращается к https, получает JSON, расшифровывает, вставляет все в переменные, и отдает массив. А так же, этот же класс выполняет создание и отправку запросов обратно к JSON по API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, такая штука называется пулом объектов.

В случае с Java, вы, вероятно, используете jackson для парсинга. Для него можно кастомный десериализатор определить с аннотацией `@JsonAnySetter`.

Но всё это не имеет смысла. Тут стоит привести известную цитату Дональда Кнута:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Нет смысла создавать пул для короткоживущих объектов. А в вашем случае, все эти объекты, создающиеся при парсинге, как я понимаю, живут не слишком долго. Сейчас GC прокачаны, и вы кастомным пулом можете наоборот замедлить работу приложения.